# Generic table storage entity retrieval

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am playing with azure table storage entity retrieval and got a good ms example

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services-v17/#retrieve-range-entities

in case ur bored to check the link

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the table client
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Get the data service context
TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

// Specify a partition query, using "Smith" as the partition key
CloudTableQuery<CustomerEntity> partitionQuery =
(from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<CustomerEntity>("people")
 where e.PartitionKey == "Smith"
 select e).AsTableServiceQuery<CustomerEntity>();

// Loop through the results, displaying information about the entity
foreach (CustomerEntity entity in partitionQuery)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
    entity.Email, entity.PhoneNumber);
}
```

now this works perfect.but i want to generalize it.. so i want to pass customerEntity as a parameter,people as parameter(easy string tablename)
and make it reusable.

so trick is for passing customerentity as parameter
pleas help :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know how to create a function which accepts a generic object type?  Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379564(v=VS.80).aspx.